# How to check if my raspberry pi's ip is static?

Tags: ip, raspberry-pi3

I found a linux guide, but my interfaces file only has comments in it. Where do I find line telling me if its static or dynamic?

Execute the following command from a terminal:

cat /etc/network/interfaces 
If your internal IP address is set as dynamic, it should contain:

iface eth0 inet dhcp
If the internal IP address is static, the result will contain:

iface eth0 inet static

[image: cat interface]

[image: cat conf]

Comment: Can you paste the content of your `/etc/network/interfaces`? I think the comments will tell us. Which version of `raspbian` do you use? Try `cat /etc/dhcpcd.conf`.

Comment: @ThomasSablik I've added both.

Comment: Is it really easier to make a screenshot, upload it it link it here? Please remove the screenshots and paste the content as text.

Comment: As you can see in the comments, you are interested in the files /etc/dhcpcd.conf and /etc/network/interfaces.d. Forget the guide you found as it is for an older version of raspbian. raspbian switched from SysVinit to systemd. With systemd it uses dhcpcd for network configuration.

Comment: @ThomasSablik I havent been able to figure out how to copy the console text from putty. Ctrl+C didn't do the job...

Comment: Ctrl+Shift+C because Ctrl+C terminates a program in terminal

Comment: @ThomasSablik I dont really understand how dhcpcd answers my questions. It's full of comments, and yes those comments do say how you can set a static ip but that is not what I want to do. I want to check if the ip is already static, just like I can on a windows pc.

Comment: If there is no entry for your interface, the IP will be set dynamically.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The guide you are reading is for some older version of raspbian, e.g. wheezy, with SystemVinit. Newer version of raspbian (jessy) uses SystemD with `dhcpcd`. It is configured with `/etc/dhcpcd.conf`. If there is no entry for your interface, it is configured dynamically (with DHCP). In your case all interfaces use DHCP.